# Running Programs not showing in gnome fallback panel

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-panel, applet

Day before yesterday when booted my PC showed a dialogue box telling some applet is missing and it had two buttons 'dont delete' and 'delete', not sure what to do I clicked the close(X) button on the top left of the dialogue box.

Since then running programs are not showing in the bottom taskbar. All other things are working fine.

I use Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. if you need any other info let me know. I use Gnome (3.4.1) installed and I prefer it over the unity interface.

[image: The screenshot of the pc which shows the lower taskbar i had and how the running programs were shown in it]
The screenshot of the pc which shows the lower taskbar i had and how the running programs were shown in it

Comment: As far as I know, Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't have any bottom taskbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution :

It required me to alt+ right_click on the taskbar and click ¨add to panel¨ and adding window list to the panel

sorry for bothering you all and thanks for taking time and answering the post

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure there is no bottom taskbar in Ubuntu...

I think you are referring to a "docking app", something like *plank* or *docky*. If thats the issue, then your docking app malfunctioned, and

> **you need to uninstall it and reinstall it**

for your running apps to appear at the bottom again

[image: Docky...an example of a docking applet that shows a bottom taskbar]

Comment: Look at the question after the revisions. The OP is actually running Gnome Fallback which has a bottom panel ("taskbar") for running applications.