# Currently Running Programs not showing in gnome fallback panel

Tags: 12.04, gnome-classic

I have exactly the same problem with gnome fallback taskbar on ubuntu 12.04 as posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/355923/running-programs-not-showing-in-gnome-fallback-panel), Currently running programs are not being displayed in taskbar
but the solution mentioned there didn't work for me as when i do Alt+Right_click, nothing happens. I posted this separate question because i don't have enough reputation to post comments on questions.

Can any one please help me with this without flag it as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using gnome fallback session follow below steps:
1)Alt+Rclick on top most panel select **NewPanel**
2)It will add one new panel at righ hand side of your screen now alt+right click on newly created panel on righ hand side and slect **move** and move it to bottom side.
3)Done.

Comment: thanks, but as i mentioned in the question, Alt+right_click has no effects, where-ever i perform this. I tried these commands but still no luck :(    `1. gconftool-2 –-shutdown
2. rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel
3. pkill gnome-panel`